# How to get proper values from Polar heart rate monitor

Tags: java, android

My android application is getting data from Polar Heart Rate Monitor through Bluetooth connection.
My problem is that I am getting such a string: 
��������������������������������������������������

My code for getting the data:

```
 final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final byte delimiter = 10; //This is the ASCII code for a newline character

    stopWorker = false;
    readBufferPosition = 0;
    readBuffer = new byte[1024];
    workerThread = new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() && !stopWorker)
            {
                try
                {
                    int bytesAvailable = mmInputStream.available();
                    if(bytesAvailable > 0)
                    {
                        byte[] packetBytes = new byte[bytesAvailable];
                        mmInputStream.read(packetBytes);
                        for(int i=0;i<bytesAvailable;i++)
                        {
                            byte b = packetBytes[i];
                            if(b == delimiter)
                            {
                                byte[] encodedBytes = new byte[readBufferPosition];
                               // System.arraycopy(readBuffer, 0, encodedBytes, 0, encodedBytes.length);
                                final String data = new String(encodedBytes, "ASCII");

                                readBufferPosition = 0;

                                handler.post(new Runnable()
                                {
                                    public void run()
                                    {
                                        pulsText.setText(data);
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                readBuffer[readBufferPosition++] = b;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (IOException ex)
                {
                    stopWorker = true;
                }
            }
        }
    });

    workerThread.start();
```

I tried to change this line in few ways but I am still getting incorrect data:

```
 final String data = new String(encodedBytes, "ASCII");
```

How can I solve this issue ?

Please help !!!

Comment: Have you looked at the raw byte values, and not as a rendered string?

Comment: it looks like your characters are above the printable range. You should look at them as integers rather than characters and see if that makes any more sense.

Comment: @erni how did you solved the problem ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sensor doesn't give you printable strings (like e.g. NMEA does) but binary data that you need to parse. You could look into the [MyTracks Polar Sensor data parser](http://code.google.com/p/mytracks/source/browse/MyTracks/src/com/google/android/apps/mytracks/services/sensors/PolarMessageParser.java) for inspiration.

You are using `available` and `read` incorrectly (but the way you use you could have luck most of the time).

Comment: Thanks for help I looked into the My tracks Polar Sensor data parser and it helped me a lot. I don't understand what is wrong with available and read in my code? It would be nice if you could explain it to me or tell my what should I change there. Thx

Comment: `read` returns the number of bytes read. You are ignoring the return value. You are only reading the number of bytes that available returned, not the number of bytes that could be read.

Comment: @his is there any standard way to read the buffer other then this polar sensor data ? as i am trying polar message parser on my Heart Rate monitor but its not working

Comment: @Hauke Ingmar Schmidt I am new to andriod I am trying to connect Polar H7 Bluetooth Smart Heart Rate Sensor to my our android app, so if i am download and integrate "MyTracks" code in my app, whether it will work?

Comment: @Suganthan MyTracks implements the connection and the parsing. It doesn't offer a library but it shouldn't be too hard to extract the relevant parts. But you need to have a look if their license (Apache License 2.0) is compatible your usage.

Answer (score 0):

The Units of Measurement (based on Raspberry Pi Challenge at JavaOne) ["Heart of Glass"](https://github.com/unitsofmeasurement/heart-of-glass) project shows, how this can be parsed into a **typesafe Heartbeat Unit** for display or transfer to other systems.